# Importar vários arquivos KMZ ao mesmo tempo

Tags: r

```
library(sf)
```

Arquivos *kmz* são arquivos do Google Earth. Tenho vários arquivos em uma pasta e gostaria de abrí-los de uma só vez no RStudio.

Defino o diretório:

```
setwd("C:/Users/fulano/Desktop/pasta_kmz")
```

Leio os arquivos kmz usando a função `st_read()` combinada com a função `unzip()`.
No entanto, preciso repetir o processo para cada arquivo *kmz*

Assim:

```
arquivo_1 <- st_read(unzip("arquivo_1.kmz"))
arquivo_2 <- st_read(unzip("arquivo_2.kmz"))
arquivo_3 <- st_read(unzip("arquivo_3.kmz"))
```

Depois de fazer isso para cada arquivo, consigo empilhá-los usando `rbind()`:

```
rbind(arquivo_1, arquivo_2, arquivo_3)
```

De certa forma, alcanço o meu objetivo.

No entanto, como eu poderia otimizar esse trabalho sem ter que ler cada arquivo *kmz* e gravá-lo em um objeto?

Tentei associar a função `unzip()` à função `list.files()`, mas não funcionou.

Imaginei que: como ao usar `list.files(pattern = ".kmz")` tenho listado todo os arquivos do tipo *kmz* que estão na pasta,
eu poderia ler todos os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
st_read(unzip(list.files(pattern = ".kmz")))
```

No entanto, não funciona.

É possível ler todos os arquivos *kmz* em uma pasta e empilhá-los em um só objeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode definir uma função para ler os ficheiros que combine `st_read` e `unzip`. Depois aplica-se essa função aos ficheiros `.kmz` e empilha a lista de bases.

```
st_read_unzip <- function(x) st_read(unzip(x))

kmzfiles <- list.files(pattern = "\\.kmz")
kmz_data <- lapply(kmzfiles, st_read_unzip)
arquivo <- do.call(rbind, kmz_data)
```

Comment: Perfeito Rui. Muito obrigado